# WPF smooth animations

Tags: wpf, animation, wpf-animation

I'm trying to animate a grid's width using DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames. I already know how to make a simple linear animation, but what I'm trying to achieve is a smooth movement that speeds up when it starts than slows down at the end. Right now I'm using LinearDoubleKeyFrame, but I've tried all the other types of DoubleKeyFrames, and none seemed to give me the effect I want. I made a [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDD0v.png) that should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to get.

[image]

Comment: Use one of the [`Easing Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/easing-functions). [`EaseInOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/media/cubicease-graph.png) looks the closest to your graph.

Comment: That's the `EaseInOut` mode of `CubicEase` to be precise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I'll try those functions later today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bradley Uffner:

> Use one of the Easing Functions. EaseInOut looks the closest to your graph.

Comment: `AccelerationRatio` and `DecelerationRatio` can be ajusted for a perfect match

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
<Trigger.EnterActions>
   <BeginStoryboard>
       <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation To="100" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="e" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
              <EaseInOut ></EaseInOut >
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
          </DoubleAnimation>
       </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
</Trigger.EnterActions>
```